# How do I restore the URL after running a bookmarklet with a keyword?

Tags: firefox, browser, bookmarklet

I like to use bookmarklets in Firefox, and my preferred way to run them is to type the bookmark keyword into the URL bar and hit Enter.  This works, but Firefox replaces the URL with the code for the bookmarklet.  How do I automatically restore the original URL?  (Without ctrl-l ctrl-z ctrl-z)

Alternatively, how do I run bookmarklets on Firefox/Windows with: <shortcut key><a few letters identifying the bookmarklet><Enter> in a way that doesn't mess up the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this addon](http://www.firefoxfacts.com/2009/01/02/add-keyboard-shortcuts-to-your-bookmarks/).
It should give you the desired options.

Comment: This does solve the problem, thanks a lot! But it is a bit annoying to duplicate my bookmarklets into this extension, and be limited to a one-character bookmark shortcut. I'm still hoping there's something better out there.

Comment: Now that I think of it, I could use Launchy to start an AHK that send keystrokes that trigger a SiteLauncher direct-to-site shortcut.